# How to use REGEXP in mysql for matching words from a text

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mysql query like :

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE '%custom%' limit 10
```

It retruns me 2 rows from my custom table.

I want to get records which contains either of any word from the text `c cu cus cust usto stom tom om m` also.

I tried below query :

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE name like '%custom%' OR name REGEXP 'c|cu|cus|cust|usto|stom|tom|om|m' limit 10
```

Above query returning me 7 records but these 7 records does not have such 2 records which 1st query result have.

How to get that? Or any other way to get these result in mysql?

**EDIT** : Here I also want to order by maximum substrings matches in second query.

Comment: There is no problem with the query. Possible to paste output of both queries here.

Comment: Do you consider `c` as a word?

Comment: Yes, my question is an example what kind of result I want to get. I am getting `custom` dynamically in my web-service and returning such records which are matching to exact keyword and its substrings as well (this is the case when keyword's spelling wrong).

Comment: So here `c` is a substring not a word?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`, we need to see the definition of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE name REGEXP 'custom' limit 10;
```

There is no need of `LIKE` with `REGEXP`, but `REGEXP` are slower then LIKE. So if your table have so many records then `REGEXP` quesries are slower.

Comment: This query return me same result as my first query, means only 2 records but I want to get total 9 records (combine from `name LIKE '%custom%'` and matching `c|cu|cus|cust|usto|stom|tom|om|m`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE name REGEXP 'custom|c|cu|cus|cust|usto|stom|tom|om|m' limit 10
```

What we did above is that we combined `custom` with the rest of the patterns, and we made them all use `REGEXP`.

Comment: No, still getting 7 records. Is REGEXP is case sensitive? My first query result have `Custom` not `custom`.

Comment: Try to add both of them `Custom|custom` , and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

You need to add word boundaries, which in MySQL are `[[:<:]]` for start of word and `[[:>:]]` for end of word:

```
SELECT name
FROM table_name
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]](c|cu|cus|cust|usto|stom|tom|om|m)[[:>:]]'
limit 10
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/729bc7/2).

Note the brackets around the alternation.

Comment: It is returning me empty result set.